# envsubst: default values for unset variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I've got a json file `input.json` like the following one:

```
{
  "variable" : "${ENV_VAR}"
}
```

of course, I can invoke envsubst from bash like the following:

```
$ export ENV_VAR=myvalue
$ envsubst < input.json > output.json
$ cat output.json
{
  "variable" : "myvalue"
}
```

Now, I wish I could set default values for variables in the input.json for the case when `ENV_VAR` is not set, like in the following example which, as unfortunately can be seen in the example below, doesn't work:

```
$ cat input.json
{
  "variable" : "${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}"
}
$ export ENV_VAR=newvalue
$ envsubst < input.json > output.json
$ cat output.json
{
  "variable" : "${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}"
}
$ unset ENV_VAR
$ envsubst < input.json > output.json
$ cat output.json
{
  "variable" : "${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}"
}
```

What's curious, if I execute the envsubst like in the following example (without involving an input file), it works

```
$ export ENV_VAR=myvalue
$ echo "value is ${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}" | envsubst
value is myvalue
$ unset ENV_VAR
$ echo "value is ${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}" | envsubst
value is defaultvalue
```

Where is the problem with the files?

Comment: The last example only appears to work, but actually doesn't. The line `echo "value is ${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}" | envsubst` is interpreted by the shell. It replaces the part `${ENV_VAR:=defaultvalue}` of the string (assigning a default value, if necessary) with the value of that variable and THEN passes the string `value is defaultvalue` (respectively `value is myvalue`) to the `echo` command, which then echo's the string and an additional line break into a pipe with `envsubst`, which in turn copies its input to its output replacing nothing, because the stream contains no variable references.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, there is no way for envsubst to accept default values for unset environment variables?

Answer (score 32):

According to `man envsubst`, `envsubst` will only ever replace references to environment variables in the form of `${VAR}` or `$VAR`. Special shell features like `${VAR:-default}` are not supported. The only thing you could do is to (re)define all variables in the environment of the `envsubst` invocation and assign local default values, if they are missing:

```
ENV_VAR="${ENV_VAR:-defaultvalue}" \
OTHER_VAR="${OTHER_VAR:-otherdefault}" \
envsubst < input.json > output.json
```

Note, that this is actually a single command line split into multiple lines each ending with a line continuation `\`. The first two lines are variable assignments, that are only effective in the environment of the executed command `envsubst` in the last line. What's happening is, that the shell will create an environment for the execution of the command (as it would always do). That environment is initially a copy of the current shell environment. Within that new environment `ENV_VAR` and `OTHER_VAR` are assigned the values of expanding the expression `${VAR:-default}`, which essentially expands to `default` unless `VAR` is defined and has a none-empty value. The command `envsubst` is executed, receiving the file `input.json` as standard-input and having its standard-output redirected to `output.json` (both is done by the shell, transparent to the command). After the command execution, the shell deletes the command environment returning to its original environment, i.e. the local variable assignments are no longer effective.

There is no way to define default values from inside the JSON file, unless you implement a program to do so yourself, or use another tool that can to that.

You could do something like the following, but it is **NOT RECOMMENDED**:

```
eval echo "$(cat input.json)" > output.json
```

which will read `input.json` into a string, and than `eval`uate the command `echo <string>` as if it was type literally, which means that any embedded `${VAR:-default}` stuff should be expanded by the shell before the string is passed to `echo`. **BUT** any other embedded shell feature will be evaluated as well, which poses a **HUGE SECURITY RISK**.

Answer (score 8):

I'm using https://github.com/a8m/envsubst and it has enhancements over the original gettext envsubst that the expressions in the template file supports default values.

The example in the README just works.

```
echo 'welcome $HOME ${USER:=a8m}' | envsubst
```

Comment: It does not work. Job is done in your shell, not in envsubst processing! Read comment at least for original question, before answering.

Comment: As @Sweavo is pointing out in an answer below, @mash 's answer does actually work, since the example supplied is single quoted which prevents the shell from performing variable interpolation. His version of `envsubst` has this feature.

Answer (score 4):

> Blockquote
> I'm using https://github.com/a8m/envsubst and it has enhancements over the original gettext envsubst that the expressions in the template file supports default values.

Similarly, a Rust variant called 'envsub' is available which also supports the default values.  See https://github.com/stephenc/envsub .

Answer (score 0):

There's also https://github.com/busyloop/envcat
which supports complex templates (so you can not only do default values but also conditions etc.).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/a8m/envsubst is a valid answer.

Lubo's  comment to mash's 6 mar 2020 answer is wrong: this example is single quoted and the shell does not substitute the variables; the other example was double quoted, inviting the shell to interpolate.

I would have commented on that answer but stack overflow's reputation system is strange.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587

Comment: Strangely I can comment here but not where my comment belongs

Comment: If you can't comment, you can suggest edits to an existing answer. Alternatively, you could elaborate here to create a unique answer.

Comment: I added a comment, but I also noticed I cannot quote users anymore using @... ‍♂️